# qt webassembly empty web page

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, webassembly, emscripten

Till now i have installed the qt webassembly, emscripten and build an qml example app with webassembly sucessfully. What my problem is when i run the webassembly app in browser, the page is empty. 
The warning message i see when inspecting the web page in chromium browser is:

```
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/include.preload.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

similary the warning msg in firefox borwser is:

```
unreachable code after return statement
```

I am using qt 5.14.1 with emscripten version 1.38.27 as suggested by qt documentation itself.
I'm testing the chartthems example from the qt creator ide itself just to test the webassembly working. But i'm getting this problem. i am using ubuntu 18 to develop qt web app.

Comment: Are you trying to run it from local disk or served through a web server? The former is likely to have issues and you should try the latter if so.

Comment: right now i'm trying to run it from local disk, 1. from qt creator ide iteself and 2. with command /path/to/emscripten/emrun --browser=firefox appname.html
 ad described in this page https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/wasm.html